# How to align vertices along average plane

Tags: vertices

I have a series of points I want to align to average plane (you can see on the left some are out plane).  I hoped I could select them all and scale them all to 0 along normal orientation, but the normal orientation is not close to the plane.

I'm in 2.79
[image]

Comment: I just realized I can fill those points to create a plane and that plane has 'correct' normals.  If anyone has a more elegant solution (especially if the points are more linear and wouldn't create a nice face) please provide it.